# How can I implement a request-response protocol without blocking while awaiting response?

Tags: java, networking, concurrency, protocols, nonblocking

I need to implement an application that is simultaneously communicating with multiple clients using a (bidirectional) request-response protocol. Previously I have implemented this using two dedicated threads for each client (one reader/reactor and one writer/initiator). The problem with this is that the thread management became quite complex and ugly. Is there any standard way of handling this, possibly even with just one thread, or at least a constant amount of threads for handling all of the clients?

This is sort of how some communication would look in a thread with the blocking implementation:

```
Command response = request("cmd1", "a", "b");
if(!response.is("OK")) {
    return;
}
response = request("cmd2", "c");
if(!response.is("OK")) {
    return;
}
response = request("cmd3");
```

Between sending the request and awaiting the corresponding response I would like for the current thread to be able to do other work, but then continue execution once the response actually arrives.

I know that it could be possible to use asynchronious IO and register Java Future/Runnable instances to run once the response for the request is received, but this easily turns into a multi-level nesting of anonymous Runnable subclasses and I suspect that it will be more pain then it is worth. This would probably result in something like the sample below, which quickly becomes highly nested and unreadable. Surely there must be an easier way?

```
request("cmd1", "a", "b", new ResponseHandler() {
    public void response(Command response) {
        if(response.is("OK")) {
            request("cmd2", "c", new ResponseHandler() {
                public void response(Command response) {
                    if(response.is("OK")) {
                        request("cmd3", new NullResponseHandler());
                    }
                }});
        }
    }});
```

I have also considered the possibility of using a dedicated [Actor framework](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/01/more-java-actor-frameworks-compared.html) to handle the request-response logic. While they look like they could help in this situation I have never worked with such frameworks before so I do not know if they are appropriate for this situation.

In short, my question is: How do I handle an arbitrary amount of request-response connections in a non-blocking way so that a constant amount of threads is sufficient? Are Actor frameworks a valid approach?

PS. I am using Java for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be quite simple using some Java NIO framework like e.g. [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). Haven't used an Actor framework so no idea if that wouldn't be a better fit though.

Basically you create one class that handles the whole communication and stores the necessary information - the framework handles the whole threading in the background you just provide a method for e.g. messageReceived and handle it there.

The downside is, that you have to basically write your own state machine which may not be that simple - but it's certainly the easiest way to use NIO.

Example:

```
enum State {
    S0, S1
}
private State state = State.S0;
public void messageReceived(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    switch(state) {
    case S0:
        // read object from channel and write appropriate response
        e.getChannel().write("HELO");  // writes are asynchronous 
        state = State.S1;
        break;
    case S1:
        // same as S0
        e.getChannel().write("DONE");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that reading the netty tutorial is still absolutely necessary, because there are things about NIO that aren't self explaining (at least they weren't for me). But there are several examples that are easy to work through which should teach you the basics.

Comment: Thank you. I have neither heard of nor used Netty before. I will definitely look into it. (When it comes to Java NIO frameworks I have only used [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/). Maybe they are similar?) By writing my own state machine I am assuming that it would handle logic in a matter similar to: `if(state == AwaitingResponseForA && response.is("OK")) { /* Perform next step and change state */ }`  Are there any available frameworks for helping with this sort of thing? (This is basically where I was hoping that Actor frameworks might be handy.)

Comment: I just noticed your edit. Thank you! That is very helpful and I am almost certainly going to proceed with such a solution, however I would very much like to find a framework for assisting in making this state machine since it might become very big and unmaintainable otherwise.

Comment: @Jiddo Yes they're probably similar. I've only used netty based on some posts here on SO where the basic agreement was that netty is the fastest and rather simple framework (I've not comparison but it's certainly not complicated). I'm not aware of any help with writing state machines (yield statements/coroutines could be useful here), but I imagine you'd still have to come up with all states and transitions anyhow in which case you've already done most of the hard work - just creating the switch and enum is a solely mechanic task. Maybe I've done just too much hardware stuff though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think using Javas Non-Blocking IO is the way to go. From there you can just add the response into an BlockingQueue. Then there can be one thread getting items from the BlockingQueue (or blokcing if no items there) and processing the responses sequentially.

Comment: Thank you. That would certainly be a place to start, but I am still unsure on how to handle the post-response dependencies in the actual application logic. For example, in the cases where an action requires multiple request-response pairs to be sent and received in order (i.e. after sending request A we must wait for response A before we can send request B etc).